# Android Manifest errors with two application tags

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to switch with a button in an other Activity(MainView), but then the app crashs and I got a lot of errors. I think this is the crucial one:
ActivityNotFoundException

Is the Manifest-file right?

```
    <application        
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.sis.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            </application>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  > 
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainView"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define two application tags. You must instead put both activities in a single application tag

```
<application        
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.sis.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".MainView"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
</application>
```

Comment: ok, thank you. But I also had it with one application tag and it doesnt work too.

Comment: oh. now it's working. Probably i had another failour last time. Now it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 application in your manifest. But you can define as many activities as you want.

Answer (score 0):

use only one application tag inside manifest

```
<application        
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.sis.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            </application>
```